# Иногда неуместно убирает точку в конце заголовка

Tags: дефект, статус-отклонено

Если в конце заголовка есть сокращение с точкой, точка автоматически удаляется.

Например: «и т. п.» или «и т. д.» превращается в «и т. п» или «и т. д».

Смотрится некрасиво.

В частности в этом вопросе: [На каком основании после «рентген» ставят дефис? Например: «рентген-кабинет», «рентген-аппарат» и т. п](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/467362/%D0%9D%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BD-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%8F%D1%82-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%81-%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BD-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82-%D1%80)

Comment: Dropping a note here - and if @Aer can be so kind as to translate it - We remove the periods from the end of all question titles by default. We don't distinguish between whether they're periods that end a sentence and those that are part of an abbreviation - we don't have a good way of identifying that, particularly not in multiple languages. That said, we'll investigate whether this rule still makes sense at all - whether we should just stop removing periods entirely. Thanks for bringing it to our attention.

Comment: @Catija Thank you for paying attention to my question. In Russian, periods at the end of titles, must not be also. This is a good practice to remove periods at the end of titles, as many people often mistakenly put a period at the end. However, the program removes periods at the end of the abbreviations “и т. п.” or “и т. д.”, which mean “etcetera” or “and so on”. It might be nice to be able to put a period by force, for example by adding a slash before a period.

Comment: I appreciate your adding the extra information for our reference. :D As we discuss this, we'll keep it in mind, too. Perhaps there's a middle path that would allow those who know how to allow it, to do so. This may require additional editing for the occasional case when a question is asked about an abbreviation such as those you mention, but it would likely require less editing than allowing them at the end of titles in all cases.

Answer (score 0):

Перевод ответа [Catija](https://rus.meta.stackexchange.com/users/189981/catija):

> We remove the periods from the end of all question titles by default. We don't distinguish between whether they're periods that end a sentence and those that are part of an abbreviation - we don't have a good way of identifying that, particularly not in multiple languages. That said, we'll investigate whether this rule still makes sense at all - whether we should just stop removing periods entirely. Thanks for bringing it to our attention.

Мы удаляем точки с конца всех заголовков вопросов по умолчанию. При этом нет разницы, конец ли это предложения или аббревиатуры, – у нас нет хорошего средства для определения этого, особенно на разных языках. Несмотря на это, мы проведем исследование о том, есть ли вообще смысл в этом правиле – нужно ли нам прекратить удалять точки во всех случаях? Спасибо за то, что обратили наше внимание на эту проблему.

Comment: Я ему уже ответил примерно три часа назад. Но спасибо, что перевели.

Answer (score 0):

(I would appreciate the translation of this answer)

While we understand the reasons for implementing exceptions to how the system currently works, these appear to be at most edge cases that, to be fully realistic and transparent, are not likely to get this prioritized in the foreseeable future. As such, I'm tagging this [status-declined](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-declined).

> Хотя мы понимаем, почему стоит изменить текущую систему, эти причины совсем не критичны и, говоря реалистично, навряд ли станут таковыми в ближайшем будущем. В связи с этим я помечаю вопрос [статус-отклонено](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%81-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%be).